# Values are coming null for all the columns in spark scala dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below dataset as input

```
816|27555832600|01|14|25|  |  
825|54100277425|14|03|25|15|  
9003|54100630574|  |  |  |  |  
809|51445926423|12|08|25|17|
```

getting below as output :

```
null|null|null|null|null|null|
825|54100277425|  14|   3|  25|  15|
null|null|null|null|null|null|
809|51445926423|  12|   8|  25|  17|
```

### expected output

```
816|27555832600|01|14|25|null|  
825|54100277425|14|03|25|15|  
9003|54100630574|null|null|null|null|  
809|51445926423|12|08|25|17|
```

I have tried the below code to load the .txt or .bz2 file.

```
val dataset = sparkSession.read.format(formatType)
        .option("DELIMITER", "|"))
        .schema(schema_new)
        .csv(dataFilePath)
```

Comment: what is the code that you tried..

Comment: val dataset = sparkSession.read.format("text)
        .option("DELIMITER", "|")
        .schema(schema_new)
        .csv(dataFilePath)

Comment: there can be blank lines in your file.. remove it and then try

Comment: i should use trim() right to remove the spaces

Comment: remove the blank lines altogether before reading in spark.

Comment: how to remove the blank lines all together using spark code

Comment: if you want to remove using spark.. then you cant read it as pipe delimited csv.. you need to read the whole line as a single column..

Comment: I can't do that. I need to read the .gzip2 compression file as text format and construct my own schema and display the proper result.

Comment: then filter after reading the file..

Comment: can you guide me how to do that

Comment: what is the schema you are providing. I mean can you provide your schema_new.

Comment: @user13748181 Can you please provide the schema that you are using at the time of reading to the question for better understanding what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your problem statement. I am using Spark 3.0.1 version to solve this use case. It working as expected. try below code snippet.

```
val sampleDS = spark.read.options(Map("DELIMITER"->"|")).csv("D:\\DataAnalysis\\DataSample.csv")
sampleDS.show()

Output ->
+----+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
| _c0|        _c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|_c5|_c6|
+----+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 816|27555832600| 01| 14| 25|   |   |
| 825|54100277425| 14| 03| 25| 15|   |
|9003|54100630574|   |   |   |   |   |
| 809|51445926423| 12| 08| 25| 17|   |
+----+-----------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Consider if your having a blank line in input data.

**Input data after adding blank line**

```
816|27555832600|01|14|25|  |  
825|54100277425|14|03|25|15|  
9003|54100630574|  |  |  |  |  
||||
809|51445926423|12|08|25|17|
```

After reading data, you can simply use `sampleDS.na.drop.show()` to remove blank or null data.

**Please note that, if you are having only blank line, then Spark does not consider in dataframe. Spark removes blank line while reading itself.**

Comment: My file is in .txt format and i can't construct schema as you mentioned.

Comment: i am getting error in your syntax. Currently I am trying below code.
val dataset = sparkSession.read.format(formatType)
        .option("DELIMITER", "|")
        .schema(schema_new)
        .csv(dataFilePath)

Comment: error has gone but output is same..full rows as null instead

Comment: i don't have any blank line in my data. I have few columns where don't have any values(contains only 2 spaces) and in the output full row coming as null.

Comment: Please Spark, Scala version details

Comment: spark version 2.4.5 and scala version 2.11

Comment: I am using Spark 3.0.1 version with Scala 2.12. There might some version compatibility, that why my code is not working for you.

Comment: might be the reason

Comment: I have modify the question .. can you please check it now.